# Access local variable in another function without using global

Tags: javascript, function, variables, local

I need to match the value of multiple `textareas` to the properties of an object. It should only be a match if :

1. the value of the `textarea` being used is equal to the person's name contained in the object **and**
2. if the index of the textarea is equal to the person's ID. (Cf
   boolean in my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/hxcpstty/1/)

To do this I need to access the object `test = {}` from this function :

```
function make_test(name, job, ID) {
    var test = {}; //local variable to be used in 'function suggest(index)'
    test.name = name;
    test.job = job;
    test.ID = ID;
    return test;
}
new make_test("Paul", "manager", 1);
new make_test("John", "employee", 2);
new make_test("Jan", "employee", 2);
```

Inside this one :

```
function suggest(index) {
    if (test.ID === index && test.name == thisInput.value) {
        thisOutput.innerHTML = "Has job : " + test.job;  //should access 'test' properties : test.name, test.job, test.ID
    }
}
```

Problem is that declaring `test = {};` as a global variable will only allow `function suggest(index)` to find 'Jan' because it is the last one I declared. But if I declare `var test = {};` as a local variable it won't work at all because `function suggest(index)` can't access `var test = {};` from outside.

This is where I'm stuck. My goal is to access `var test = {};` within `suggest()` to get every person's job depending on their `name` and `ID`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need an array to hold references to all of the people, or, if employee ID is unique (which it is *not* in your example) you could use an object instead of an array. Also, you don't need `new` when calling the function. So: `var employees = []; employees.push(make_test(...));`.

Comment: @Jecoms It was suggested that OP ask another Question as to `suggest` function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968429/dynamically-access-function-object-property#comment67216922_39968451

Comment: @nnnnnn :That's what I tried to do at first, but then they won't have the other two properties I need to match them (job and ID) unless I push objects in the array ? I initially wanted to avoid using array of objects since iterating through the array plus the object will print multiple times the same results. I may be wrong though, since I'm still trying to expand my knowledge in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your employee IDs don't seem to be unique, I'd suggest you store all the people in an array, then in your `suggest()` function you can search through the array to check for a match (click *Run code snippet* to try it out):

```js
function make_test(name, job, ID) {
  var test = {};
  test.name = name;
  test.job = job;
  test.ID = ID;
  return test;
}

var people = [];

people.push(make_test("Paul", "manager", 1));
people.push(make_test("John", "employee", 2));
people.push(make_test("Jan", "employee", 2));

function suggest(index) {
  var thisInput = document.getElementById("textarea" + index);
  var thisOutput = document.getElementById("output" + index);

  thisOutput.innerHTML = "Has job:";

  for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].ID === index && people[i].name == thisInput.value) {
      thisOutput.innerHTML = "Has job: " + people[i].job; //should access 'test' properties : test.name, test.job, test.ID
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea onkeyup="suggest(1)" name="response" id="textarea1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    <td><div id="output1">Has job :</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea onkeyup="suggest(2)" name="response" id="textarea2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    <td><div id="output2">Has job :</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that it doesn't make sense to call your `make_test()` function with `new`, because you manually create a new object inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is perfect ! I also learned new tricks which will help me to debug further problems.

Comment: You're welcome. There are ways this can be made tidier, but I thought I'd stick with a basic implementation that only modifies your existing code just enough to get you up and running.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @nnnnnn, you can store object returned by `make_test` in an array; pass array to `suggest`, use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate array

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function make_test(name, job, ID) {
    var test = {}; //local variable to be used in 'function suggest(index)'
    test.name = name;
    test.job = job;
    test.ID = ID;
    return test;
  }

  var thisInput = document.querySelector("input");

  var thisOutput = document.querySelector("output");

  var arr = [];

  arr.push(make_test("Paul", "manager", 1),
    new make_test("John", "employee", 2),
    new make_test("Jan", "employee", 2));

  function suggest(index, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(test) {
      if (test.ID === index && test.name == thisInput.value) {
        thisOutput.innerHTML = "Has job : " + test.job;
      }
    })
  }

  suggest(1, arr);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Paul">
<output></output>
```